# Small script to verify hash of a downloaded file

Tags: bash, hashcode

You know how whenever you download a file you should really compare the hash of the download to the one provided on the website? This makes absolute sense, but it's a pain to do it letter for letter, digit for digit. So, I wrote this little script to take care of the job. Any comments are welcome.

```
#!/bin/bash

# hash_checker - program to verify a downloaded file

error_exit()
{
    echo "$1" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

usage="usage: hash_checker downloaded_file hash_provided -a algorithm"
downloaded_file=
hash_given=
hash_calc=
algo="sha256"

# check if file and hash were provided
if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    error_exit "$usage"
fi

# parsing the provided hash and file
downloaded_file="$1"
hash_given="$2"

# parsing the algorithm, if provided
if [ "$3" != "" ]; then
    if [ "$3" = "-a" ]; then
        algo="$4"
    else
        error_exit "$usage"
    fi
fi

# check if input is a valid file
if [ ! -f "$downloaded_file" ]; then
    error_exit "Invalid file! Aborting."
fi

# calculate the hash for the file
hash_calc="$($algo'sum' $downloaded_file)"
hash_array=($hash_calc)
hash_calc=${hash_array[0]}

# compare the calculated hash to the provided one
if [ "$hash_calc" = "$hash_given" ]; then
    echo "The hashes match. File seems to be valid."
else
    echo "The hashes do not match. File does not seem to be valid."
fi
```

Comment: Why not just use the `-c` option to `sha1sum` or `md5sum` to do the comparison?

Comment: Didn't know that was an option. Kinda expected something like this must exist, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notes:

- I'd use `getopts` for arg parsing -- lots of examples on stackoverflow about how to use it.
- [always quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)
- you should validate the algorithm:

  ```
  sum_exe="${algo}sum"
  if ! type -P "$sum_exe" >/dev/null; then
      error_exit "'$algo' is an unknown checksum algorithm"
  fi
  ```
- have the checksum program read from stdin, then you don't have to do your <strike>incorrect</strike> unsafe word parsing since the program will not print a filename

  ```
  hash_calc=$( "$sum_exe" < "$downloaded_file" )
  ```

  ---

  As the above doesn't work, let's use `read` from a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)

  ```
  read -r hash_calc _ < <("$sum_exe" < "$downloaded_file")
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your notes. Reading from stdin the filename is not printed, but `  -` is appended to the hash, and thus the test fails. Is there a way around that other than more word parsing?

Comment: I've updated my answer